# head and tail in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am working elixir and trying to achieve data in some specific form with head and tail method.

I have this kind of data `["09:89-87:45", "23:23-23:23", "65:65-23:04"]`

With doing head and tail? can i get this data into `[["09:89-87:45"], ["23:23-23:23"], ["65:65-23:04"]]` form?

What I am doing right now is not working good.

```
iex(14)> defmodule Gy do                                                
...(14)>   def get_head_tail([head|tail]) do
...(14)>    [[head], get_head_tail(tail)]       
...(14)>   end
...(14)>   def get_head_tail([]) do
...(14)>     []
...(14)>   end
...(14)> end
```

it returns as `[["09:89-87:45"], [["23:23-23:23"], [["65:65-23:04"], []]]]`
anyhelp will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def wrap([]), do: []
def wrap([a|bs]) do
  [[a]|wrap(bs)]
end
```

You used `,` instead of `|`, which meant that you created a list with two elements, rather than appending an element to the head of the list.

```
[1|[2|[3]]] == [1|[2,3]] == [1,2,3]
```

compared to

```
[1,[2,[3]]]
```

The second thing is that you defined the special case of `get_head_tail([])` after the general case. Your version still works, but it's a good habit to put special cases first, because the first matching expression, top down, is the one that is used. The next function you write might not have mutually exclusive clauses, and then the order would matter.

Comment: In this case second mistake is not a mistake, since `[]` won’t match `[head|tail]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa okey, it doesn't change the outcome of the program in this case, but it's not the way most people write Erlang/Elixir, because it could've made a difference in a similar function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Enum.map/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) to achieve this result:

```
iex> Enum.map(["09:89-87:45", "23:23-23:23", "65:65-23:04"], &([&1]))
[["09:89-87:45"], ["23:23-23:23"], ["65:65-23:04"]]
```

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq Sorry, Isn't this returns the same result you want to achieve? Then I didn't get it sorry. Maybe only first and last element should be wrapped in a separate array? Could you please provide desired result for a list with 4 or 5 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Since, you go through full list and want to have exact number of elements as in original list, you can simply use list comprehension:

```
for x <-["09:89-87:45", "23:23-23:23", "65:65-23:04"], do: [x]
```